# Is Multi-AZ RDS a solution for slow database speeds overseas?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have an app based in Australia, which runs quick enough within Australia, Asia and the US. However, in Europe/UK, it's unbearably slow.

The data being sent across is reasonably negligible, so I'm assuming it's latency communicating with the database. I've never attempted to horizontally-scale a database, so I'm not sure where to start.

Would using AWS Multi-AZ RDS work for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Multi-AZ RDS will not work in this case as the purpose of Multi-AZ is [fault tolerance/high availability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) rather than performance:

> Amazon RDS provides high availability and failover support for DB instances using Multi-AZ deployments.

Beyond that simple answer, this is an architecture question that will be highly dependent on your application and the cost/benefit of removing this latency. From a technical perspective, to remove regional latency you should consider multi-region architectures. This may be at the database level, a cache level, or require a full active-active multi-region architecture depending on your application and cost considerations. For example:

1. [AWS Re:invent multi-region architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMrfzR4zyM4)
2. [Multi-region active-active](https://read.acloud.guru/why-and-how-do-we-build-a-multi-region-active-active-architecture-6d81acb7d208) discussion
3. [Cross-region read replicas](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/)